# react-big-calender how to get hover method and how can we give borders to date slot?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am not getting any doc that can give me solution on hover method of react big calender and also apply css to date slots.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `eventStyleGetter` in this way:

```
const eventStyleGetter = ( start, isSelected) => { 
    var style = { 
        //whatever styles you wana give 
    }; 
    return { className: "yourclassname", style: style, }; 
};
```

And then in your component you can use this `eventPropGetter={eventStyleGetter}` way.

Answer (score 0):

For set pop-up on hover method we can use 'eventWrapper' with component of big calendar, like this:

```js
<BigCalendar
  localizer={localizer}
  culture={calenderCult}
  events={events}
  resizable
  views={['week', 'day']}
  defaultView={BigCalendar.Views.WEEK}
  eventPropGetter={(this.eventStyleGetter)}
  components={
    {
      eventWrapper: ({ event, children }) => (
        <div
          onMouseOver={
            e => {
              e.preventDefault();
            }
          }
        >
          <Popover placement="rightTop" content={this.handleEnablePopover(event)} title="xyz">
            {children}
          </Popover>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
/>
```

In handleEnablePopover function:

```js
// popup jsx for event on hover
handleEnablePopover = (event) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Row>
        <Col lg={12} xs={24}>
          <span>abc: <p>{event.abc}</p></span>
        </Col>
        <Col lg={12} xs={24}>
          <span>xyz: <p>{event.xyz}</p></span>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For set css style, you can use this eventPropGetter={this.eventStyleGetter} way, like this:

```js
// set color, based on event get from BE
eventStyleGetter = (event) => {
  var style = {
      backgroundColor: event.bgColor,
      borderColor: event.borderColor
  };
  return {
      style: style
  };
}
```